# An example of projective variety without rank 2 stable bundle？

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is: does there exists an example of projective variety that there is no rank 2 stable vector bundle over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the projective line over an algebraically closed field all vector bundles are sums of line bundles, so no plane bundle is slope stable: any rank 2 vector bundle is of the form $E = \mathcal O(n)\oplus\mathcal O(m)$, for some $n\ge m$. Then $\mathcal O(n)$ has bigger slope than $E$:
$$
\nu(\mathcal O(n)) = n \ge \frac{n+m}{2} = \frac{\deg E}{\operatorname{rk} E} = \nu(E).
$$

Comment: Surely you mean over the projective line?

Comment: Wait, I did write projective line! Why did someone edit it to projective plane?

Comment: Thank you so much. I forget the projective line at all :)

Comment: That one's my fault on the edit - I saw "plane bundle" and assumed you meant a bundle over the plane instead of a rank-2 vector bundle. My apologies.